# O que está a causar este erro? jquery.php?version=1.3.2&gzip=0&farfuture=0:1

Tags: php, jquery

Estou com dificuldades em identificar este erro que aparece numa das páginas de um website:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
>   jquery.php?version=1.3.2&gzip=0&farfuture=0:1

Fiz umas pesquisas e parece que está relacionado com o `Fututre Expire header`, mas também acho que poderá ser a versão do JQuery estar desactualizada. O site foi criado através do Joomla. Se alguém me puder ajudar a identificar o problema, fico muito agradecido.

Aqui segue o jquery.php de onde surgiu o erro:

```
<?php
// no direct access
defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted access' );

jimport( 'joomla.plugin.plugin' );

/**
* jQuery loading plugin
*
* @version      1.0
*/

//TODO: Create translation ini files

class plgSystemJquery extends JPlugin {

function plgSystemJquery(& $subject, $config) {
    parent::__construct($subject, $config);
}


function _getPath() {
    $mainframe =& JFactory::getApplication();

    $gzip = $this->params->get('gzip', 0);
    $farfuture = $this->params->get('farfuture', 0);
    $version = $this->params->get('version','1.3.2');

    $path = 'plugins/system/jquery/';

//      if (!$gzip && !$farfuture) {
 //         $file = 'jquery-'.$version.'.min.js';
 //     } else {
        $file = 'jquery.php?version='.$version.'&amp;gzip='.$gzip.'&amp;farfuture='.$farfuture;         
//      }
// Prepend ../ if we're in the backend
        if($mainframe->isAdmin()) {
        $path = '../'.$path;
    }

    return $path.$file;

}

function onAfterDispatch() {

    $doc =& JFactory::getDocument();

    if ($doc->getType() == 'html' && $this->params->get('bottomscript', 0) == 1) {
        $version = $this->params->get('version','1.3.2');
        $js = '<script type="text/javascript">if (typeof(jQuery) == "undefined" || (typeof(jQuery) != "undefined" && jQuery.fn.jquery != "'.$version.'") )
            document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src=\''.self::_getPath().' \' type=\'text/javascript\'%3E%3C/script%3E"));</script>';
        JResponse::appendBody($js);

        $js = '<script type="text/javascript">$jquery = jQuery.noConflict();</script>';
        JResponse::appendBody($js);

    }

    if ($doc->getType() == 'html' && $this->params->get('bottomscript', 0) == 0) {

        // Add jquery to the scripts
        $doc->addScript(self::_getPath());

        // Get head data
        $headdata = $doc->getHeadData();

        // Take the scripts part
        $scripts = $headdata['scripts'];

        // Reverse the array so we can pick jquery easily
        $revscripts = array_reverse($scripts,true);

        // Take the jquery field
        $keys = array_keys($revscripts);
        $key = $keys[0];
        $jqueryscript = $revscripts[$key];

        // Reconstruct the scripts array with jquery as first
        $newscripts[$key]  = $jqueryscript;
        foreach ($scripts as $path=>$type) {
            $newscripts[$path] = $type;
        }

        // Set the new head data
        $doc->setHeadData (array('scripts'=>$newscripts));

    }

}

}
```

Modificações no código:

```
class plgSystemJquery extends JPlugin {

function plgSystemJquery(&$subject, $config) {
    parent::__construct($subject, $config);
}

function _getPath() {
    $mainframe =& JFactory::getApplication();

      if(!JFactory::getApplication()->get('jquery')){
 JFactory::getApplication()->set('jquery',true);
 $mainframe = JFactory::getDocument();
 $mainframe->addScript(JURI::root() . "templates/movimentoeleclerc/scripts/jquery.js");
```

}

Comment: @Daniel Omine  Obrigado pela resposta, juntei o código, achei que fosse um erro mais fácil de identificar. Ainda sou bastante inexperiente em php, apenas sei o básico, peço desculpa se não fui tão claro quanto deveria. Tem alguma sugestão em como fazer o debug? Eu penso que nao seja falhas de pontuação porque este php já esteve funcional, estou mais inclinado para o corrompimento do  arquivo. O site sofreu uma migração do joomla e surgiram alguns problemas, e com isso alterações no código que podem estar a causar conflitos

Comment: @Daniel Omine  o erro aparece em todas, mas apenas na console quando faço "inspeccionar elemento", as páginas funcionam bem em princípio. Eu é que fui encarregado de tentar resolver os erros que aparecem na console. O plugin que o código está a tentar acessar é o system - jquery que também já verifiquei e está na versão 1.3.2.

Comment: Verifica a ordem com que chamas os plugins

Comment: @msm.oliveira  Pode dar-me alguma dica de como fazer isso?

Comment: É a primeira vez que ouço falar em joomla e nunca usei php. Uma das coisas que poderá estar a causaro erro pode ser a ordem com que chamas os plugins: http://prntscr.com/7ablt7 . Isto tem uma ordem, pois uns plugins precisam de outras classes que também têm que ser importadas

Comment: Agora que fala nisso, há outro erro que me aparece nos chamamentos dos plugins:  <<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->baseurl; ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template?>/scripts/layout.js"></script>   Diz que $ não é uma função. Poderá ser isso?

Comment: veja o modo apropriado de adicionar o arquivo javascript: https://docs.joomla.org/Adding_JavaScript

Comment: @angelfmf se isso diz que $ não é função então é porque não deves estar a fazer o import do jquery como deve ser

Comment: @Daniel Omine  Não, já fui ver e o joomla não está a utilizar o smarty. mas sim, os templates têm todos pastas de script, css e php. Não entendo muito de templates mas neste website está tudo dividido assim. E obrigado pelo o documento, vai ser muito +útil

Comment: então qual sistema de template está usando ?

Comment: @Daniel Omine  Hathor admin template

Comment: @msm.oliveira Tentei mudar o import através deste link[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12471067/importing-jquery-into-joomla] mas sem sucesso. o código que modifiquei está em último lugar na pergunta.

Comment: @Daniel Omine Eu disse "Hathor admin template" está aqui um video que fala sobre o template, caso esteja interessado em ver. [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZXOjzpx22r4]

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24216/discussion-between-angelfmf-and-daniel-omine).

Comment: desculpe, não participo de bate papo, ainda mais para resolver trabalho alheio..